# BSF Preprocessor relative file name

Tags: jmeter

I need to have script relative file name (relative to test plan file) in [BFS Prepocessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_PreProcessor) in JMeter. I need something like: "../scripts/commonscript.js" but this doesn't work, I have to use the whole path and this is very bad for version control.
Is there some variable/property/function so I can use path relative to test plan file?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I think path will be relative to ApacheJmeter.jar that is in /bin folder

Comment: yes but I need path to be relative to test plan file (*.jmx)! Not to JMeter location. IMO this is more natural.

Comment: Maybe but that's not the contract :-) , I updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at BSFSampler code, FileName is relative to /bin.

So the way to to it :

1. Add a User Defined Variables called scriptDir
   With value ${__P(scriptDir, dfltvalue)}
2. Use it in your path as ${scriptDir}/
3. Define this variable at startup using -JscriptDir=

Comment: This post has a similar answer but I believe it to be more useable:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785597/jmeter-upload-file-with-relative-path-from-the-jmx-file

Comment: No the solution described elsewhere uselessly makes usage of Beanshell. Solution here only uses standard function so it will be more maintainable and more performing