# JMeter upload file with relative path from the jmx file

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a HTTP Request Sampler in JMeter to automate uploading file to a http service. Is there a way to set the "File Path" in the "Send Files With the Request" to a relative path from the location of the jmx file?

Comment: As of JMeter 5.6 the `File.path` named `stringProp` property in the .jmx file may be set to a relative value without any `__BeanShell` or custom variable and it simply works. (tested in the multipart request).

Answer (score 56):

Yes. (This was confirmed in JMeter v2.9)

You can use the following BeanShell expression in the filename input field:

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}<YOUR FILENAME HERE>
```

So if your file, "**upload.jpg**" was located in the same folder as your JMX test file, the complete value would be

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}upload.jpg
```

To keep it a bit cleaner, add a "User defined variables" config element where you assign the base of the expression to a variable e.g

`SCRIPT_PATH = ${__BeanShell( ...etc`

Then your file path input value would read a more readable:

`${SCRIPT_PATH}upload.jpg`

Comment: This worked for me. However, I wonder if there's a better way to make this association rather than using the User Defined Variables element, as I might want to use this in multiple different test cases. Surely there must be some way to tell jmeter to always use the relative path?

Answer (score 8):

I'm under version 2.11, and the BeanShell script didn't work for me, to make the CSV file relative, and so to make a relative path you simple need to use this `~/filename.csv`. This would mean that the CSV file exist in the same directory as the JMX file. But I guess you can modify it to this for example `~/../results_dir/filename.csv` etc..

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer here http://kisbigger.blogspot.com/2013/09/pointing-to-files-with-relative-paths.html which was ...

- step 1: Create a user-defined-variable Config element to your
  project.
- step 2: Add a new variable CONFIG_PATH
- step 3: in the value
  column place this code :  ${__BeanShell(import
  org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
  FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}
- step 4 : use the variable
  name wherever you want like ${CONFIG_PATH}\config.xml

having a filename.csv in the same folder as the jmx and putting ~/filename.csv with JMeter 2.11 and a newer JAVA did not work

Comment: This is actually the same as [the most upvoted answer given 4 years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213912/426371), although I must admit yours is more cut-and-dried.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: it now works with the relative path.

I tried the solution with the user-defined variable, but then I saw that JMeter is resolving it as a relative path anyway.

As of JMeter 5.6, the `File.path` named `stringProp` property in the .jmx file may be set to a relative value without any `__BeanShell` or user-defiend variable and it simply works. (tested in the multipart request).

In the UI mode and the CLI mode it seams to be resolving the relative paths to be relative to the location of the .jmx file.